# How to represent question mark '?' in Apache mod_jk JkMount?

Tags: apache, mod-jk

I have a question regarding mod_jk of Apache.

I am writing a JkMount sentence which redirect a URL that contains a question mark to a worker.

The syntax is something like:

> JkMount /jmx-console/?configuration
>   worker-tradeservice-configuration

However, the question mark seems need to be escaped. I don't know how to represent it in the mod_jk syntax.

I tried:

> JkMount /jmx-console/\?configuration
>   myworker
>
> JkMount /jmx-console/\?configuration
>   myworker
>
> JkMount /jmx-console/*configuration
>   myworker

And all of them don't work.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to work. The part of the URL after the `?` is not part of the path, it's the query string, and the path component is what `JkMount` tries to match against.

My suggestion is that you combine `JkMount` with mod-rewrite, using the latter to rewrite the requests to convert query strings into paths, and then `JkMount` those paths accordingly. Mod-rewrite is a complex beast, though, so you'll need to read up on that.